# use of which as a conjunction in a conditional clause

Tags: conditional-constructions

> Constructing a shelter is a great act. Especially if there is a need
> for a shelter in a town, in which case the reward is limitless.

I see something unusual in the word 'which' here. I think there should be 'this'. I don't think if the conjunction 'which' grammatically fits in the main clause after the If-clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the grammar. *Which* refers to something previously mentioned, and introduces more information about it.

> This is the umbrella which I bought yesterday.
>
> This is the box in which I keep my treasured possessions.

*In which case* refers to the circumstances of the town really needing a shelter.

Comment: Some more examples of "in which case" to talk about a possible or imagined situation: "It may be raining, **in which case** we will meet indoors"; "I am considering going back to school, **in which case** I would need to take out a loan".